# How can I hide columns and change their order?

Tags: apache-poi, jxls

Currently I'm using `jxls` and it works just fine. The basic element I use is `transformXLS` from `net.sf.jxls.transformer.XLSTransformer` class. In the template I use `</jx:forEach>`. The simplest use-case, I think. The question is, can I hide columns and change their order dynamically ? I see `setColumnsToHide()` in aforementioned class so I gues it is possible (I am not sure though), but Is it possible to change column orders too ?

**EDITED**:
maybe I will ask about the same thing in a different way. Can I achieve that `${el.${col.rate}}` in any way ?

```
<jx:forEach items="${cols}" var="col">  ${col.name} </jx:forEach>
<jx:forEach items="${elements}" var="el">       
<jx:forEach items="${cols}" var="col">  ${el.${col.rate}}   </jx:forEach>
</jx:forEach>
```

*`${col.rate}` is the column name for `el`